# A simple angular directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a beginner. These are copied from the example. They can't be working now.

```
 <html ng-app>
 <head>
 <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
 <script >
 var app = angular.module("App", []);
 app.directive("antest", function(){
    debugger;
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        templateUrl: "b.html",
        replace: true
        };
 });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <antest></antest>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What is it doing, not doing?  What is your question here?

Comment: `b.html` wouldn't hurt to include

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've named your module "App". So you need ng-app="App" for it to work.

Comment: Thanks, debugger is working now, But the b.html content is still not print out.

Comment: what does b.html look like?

Comment: b.html:
<div>
 <ul>
  <li>Windows</li>
  <li>Linux</li>
  <li>Unix</li>
 </ul>
</div>

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/StAR/Desktop/Learning/ng-test/b.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: @Tan You need a proper http-server to correctly run/test your app.

Comment: I know what happened now. Thank you for your help.